# Exclude specific keys of dict when passing to variable

Tags: python

im trying to exclude some key when passing a dict to a variable. for example.

```
dict1 = {
    'id': 1,
    'name' : 'John Woe',
    'flag' : True,
    'position' : 'Developer'
}
```

Now i would like to exclude the key `flag` or any specified keys when passing it to `dict2` variable. Normally i can simple hardcodedly assign it but i want a dynamic approach.

Such as this:

```
dict2 = dict1.exclude(['flag', 'position'])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
keys_to_exclude = set(('flag',))
dict2 = {k:v for k,v in dict1.iteritems() if k not in keys_to_exclude}
```

As a response to the criticism in the comments about this being `O(MN)` - `keys_to_exclude` can be a set and it will make it `O(N)` with less burden to garbage collection, compared to `copy/pop` solution.

Comment: it is possible to exclude 1 or more keys?

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab yes, see my update.

Comment: Do you know if doing `dict1.copy()` and then `dict2.pop('flag')` could be more efficient in case of dicts with a large number of keys?

Comment: @VMRuiz i think it is ok because it can help with many keys in just 2 line of codes.

Comment: I mean its O(N) vs O(MN), but it really depends on the use cases, and that is outside the scope of the question at hand

Comment: I find this answer hepful :)

Comment: For Python 3 use dict.items() instead of dict.iteritems()