# How to extract all fields minus a couple from a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that I can create a subset of a dictionary by the following code:

```
#I get only fields a,b and c from the old dict
newdict = {k: olddict.get(k, None) for k in ('a', 'b', 'c')}
```

but suppose I need all fields, **except "d" and "e"**..is there a way to reverse this code?

Comment: More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618542/exclude-specific-keys-of-dict-when-passing-to-variable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just inverse it with `not` keyword:

`newdict = {k: olddict.get(k, None) for k in olddict if k not in ('d', 'e')}`